# How to get a history from ethers.js on my own ERC-20 token

Tags: blockchain, ethers.js

How can I get the amount of tokens sent by me?
After I deployed my token in kovan  test network, I made some transaction and after I try to got the history of this transaction with :

```js
const networkProvider = new ethers.providers.EtherscanProvider(network)
const currentAddress = await currentSigner.getAddress();
let currentHistory = await networkProvider.getHistory(currentAddress);
```

In response to the function, I get array with objects like inside of object I have this information:

```js
accessList: null
blockHash: "0x735cde05c66ddd8af76c0de3c08e41c9c7cf852a22756546bf2ff063b478836e"
blockNumber: 31031876
chainId: 0
confirmations: 36875
creates: null
data: "0xa9059cbb00000000000000000000000001bf19665c85053c5de3c8cdc9170e4fcd3317c5000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006b8d87f0514700000"
from: "0x20f6c0E4e9Fb04F16031dB112f4cFb4446322258"
gasLimit: BigNumber {_hex: '0xce9b', _isBigNumber: true}
gasPrice: BigNumber {_hex: '0x908a9047', _isBigNumber: true}
hash: "0x9dcf3942a3c1c5024b47a11af51a9f908f957aa62b70f1fa045fe5fda3f4b944"
nonce: 11
timestamp: 1650024704
to: "0xb9eBD829546efFCAB00d74B1448D0c6b7E32ADba"
transactionIndex: 2
type: 0
value: BigNumber {_hex: '0x00', _isBigNumber: true}
[[Prototype]]: Object
length: 17
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Like in property, "value" is the value of my token on Ether. But I want to know the amount of how much of my tokens I sent. Can I get the information from this object?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
await provider.getTransaction('TxHash')

// OR

await provider.getTransactionReceipt('TxHash')
```